# Inline search bar on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add a in-line search bar on the left on the navigation menu. It is a button which reveals a text box next to it to allow the user to enter hat they want. I have tried to position it in-line but for some reason it appears ontop of the menu icon on smaller devices.

I was also wondering how I could have the text box fade in and out over the menu elements instead of it appearing next to them.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="navbar-header">

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">

            <button id='search-button' class='btn btn-default '><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></button>

            <div id='search-form' class="form-group">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span id='search-icon' class="input-group-addon"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>

          <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
    </div>


  </div>
</nav>
<script type='text/javascript'>

      $(function(){

         $("#search-button, #search-icon").click(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             $("#search-button, #search-form").toggle();
         });
      })  
</script>
```

I forgot to mention, I am also unable to post this form anywhere since the search button hides the textbox. What could I do to fix this?

Comment: Can u make a Plunkr or JSFiddle? Would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @EricMitjans https://jsfiddle.net/egp6fLog/

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem. Is the view OK for PC? Is the problem only on mobile? In the jsfiddle I see no issue, button toggles the search box in view and off view ok. And it is positioned as the first menu item. What exactly do you want to accomplish?

Comment: @EricMitjans Please take a look at the images I have provided. Mobile is fine, however when in desktop and the search button is pressed the menu links are pushed to the right. I want the search bar that appears to cover all the links instead of pushing them right.

Comment: @EricMitjans Also you can see the the search bar icon has already pushed the links right. How can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help: the search bar will appear over the links on click and the button will remain exposed on all viewports instead of being hidden once you're under 768px. See example.

```js
$(".btn-search").click(function(e) {
  $("#search-input, #btn-go").fadeToggle();
});
$(".hasclear").keyup(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.next('span').toggle(Boolean(t.val()));
});

$(".clearer").hide($(this).prev('input').val());

$(".clearer").click(function() {
  $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
/**Custom**/

body,
html {
  margin-top: 60px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
  background: #f5f5f5;
}
.formSearch {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.formSearch .has-feedback span.glyphicon {
  padding: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: #444;
}
.btn.btn-search,
.btn.btn-search:hover,
.btn.btn-search:focus {
  background: none;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}
#search-input,
#search-input:focus {
  height: 50px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}
.input-group-btn #btn-go {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search"> <span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-search" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

        </button>
        </span>
        <div class="has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control hasclear" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="clearer glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>

        </div> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-go" type="button"> Search</button>
      </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Forums</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Sponsorship</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Bespoke Events</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Vacancies</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">Boostrap Search Bar</div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, I need the links to be fixed in the center of the nav bar, I tried one method but i think thats why my links are not being covered

Comment: Hi, This worked! However I have a slight issue where the li elements i have on the page cover the dropdown menu when in mobile and in desktop the entire . Also I have been trying to get the toggle to fade using "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  } but that doesnt seem to work and would setting the width of the form to 100% cover all the links on the nav?

Comment: This is how I would do it personally. See updated example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was after! However I noticed that the menu doesn't seem to work in mobile. Is this because of the links I am using to bootstrap?

Comment: It could depending on the order of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want your search bar to overlay the links.

You can create a css class:

```
   .fix-menu {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

and add it to your links list:

```
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav fix-menu">
```

[jsfiddle updated](https://jsfiddle.net/vmateus/t5ac82tx/1/)

Comment: Hi, I Just tried this on my project file but does not seem to work. The fiddle however does.

Comment: I need the links to be centred in the menu