# Image ontop of bootstrap nav bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to add an image ontop of a bootstrap navbar however I am unable to add one with additional "bars" in the nav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the image into the navbar since you're using a fixed position for your navigation. This post may also help with other functionality it looks like you're trying to implement: [SO Bootstrap Search Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32350542/inline-search-bar-on-bootstrap/32355283#32355283)

```js
$(".btn-search").click(function(e) {
  $("#search-input, #btn-go").fadeToggle();
});
$(".hasclear").keyup(function() {
  var t = $(this);
  t.next('span').toggle(Boolean(t.val()));
});

$(".clearer").hide($(this).prev('input').val());

$(".clearer").click(function() {
  $(this).prev('input').val('').focus();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.banner {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
.banner img {
  height: 100px;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  border: none;
  border-top: 6px solid #266080;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #266080;
  background: #444;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-toggle {
  z-index: 1;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
  background: #444;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.navbar .formSearch {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
.navbar .formSearch .has-feedback span.glyphicon {
  padding: 7px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  pointer-events: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar .btn.btn-search,
.navbar .btn.btn-search:hover,
.navbar .btn.btn-search:focus {
  background: none;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar #search-input {
  height: 50px;
  background: #444;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}
.navbar #search-input:focus {
  height: 50px;
  background: #444;
  color: #DFE82A;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  display: none;
}
.navbar .input-group-btn #btn-go {
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(17, 18, 19, 1) color: #fff;
  display: none;
}
.well.well-dark {
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.footer {
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #444;
  line-height: 85px;
  border-top: 6px solid #266080;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #266080;
}
ul.footer-nav > li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: right;
}
ul.footer-nav > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
/* Media Qs */

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom navbar-top">
  <section class="banner" id="banner">
    <img src="http://scottace.com/img/css3-icon.png">
  </section>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
      <form class="formSearch" role="search"> <span class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-search" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

        </button>
        </span>
        <div class="has-feedback">
          <input type="text" class="form-control hasclear" id="search-input" placeholder="Search for..."> <span class="clearer glyphicon glyphicon-remove form-control-feedback"></span>

        </div> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" id="btn-go" type="button"> Search</button>
      </span>
        </span>
    </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg well-dark">
    <h1>Boostrap Search Bar</h1>

  </div>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
    has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled
    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
    and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
    the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic
    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem
    Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
    It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
    publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
    took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
    standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the
    printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries,
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="footer-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Copyright &#169; 2015</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Would I be able to use this if the navbar was not fixed? If not what would i need to change?

Comment: See this answer also for the a non fixed nav: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628502/bootstrap-3-centered-nav-and-image-behind/32643509#32643509

Comment: Hi, I managed to get it to work, However When i add a sticky footer te main content gets pushed down near the footer. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's hard to say to be honest.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbr5a6wm/ Heres a JSFiddle. I have added the footer and you can see the main body elements have been pushed down. Also i tried to add "bars" like the ones in the header using border-top/bottom but that doesnt seem to display the bars. any idea why this is happening?

Comment: I didn't see any CSS in your fiddle concerning borders and you seem to have added some divs that cause the layout to shift down. See updated answer and please mark it as answered if it works so it's removed from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Hi, Ive just noticed that this footer isnt sticky. It ends when the content finishes, not stuck to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Add position: fixed; to the .footer class and add margin-bottom: 100px; to the body class (you can use whatever height is equal to or greater than your footer is set to, in the above example it's 100px;)

Comment: Hi, I've been doing some cross browser check to see if everything works fine but I've noticed on Firefox the search bar does not expand across the whole screen. It only appears on the left side with a fixed width. What could be the reason behind this? I don't see anything in my CSS or HTML that would cause this to happen.

Comment: Ok I have fixed this issue. Adding a width of 100% to the form displays properly on Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the image, I wouldn't use percentage for width then vh for height as thia could cause distortion. Stick with one and centre it.

The links however could use a percentage width of the container they are in to make them fill the entire screen as per your design.

Comment: Ok, ill try change that. Would you know how i could add those bars that are in the design? The ones at the top of the header, bottom and above the nav content

Comment: Make two divs one before and one after your image and give them widths of 100% and a height of say 10px and make the background colour red(or whatever you want)

Comment: Sorry one between the links one after and one before the image then play around with the height to get what you want

Comment: What percentage would I give the li? I added a percentage but when the i test this on a smaller device the links aren't being displayed properly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pbr5a6wm/1/ Try this?, the reason they go when the screen is smaller is because it turns into a mobile friendly menu btw.